# Increased minSdkVersion, now older devices can't install the older app version that supported them

Tags: android

I increased the `minSdkVersion` from 16 to 21. I thought that when a user with an old device visits the play store, they will be able to download the previous APK that has it set to 16, and only the new devices will see the latest version.

However, when I visited the play store with a device running sdk 16, I just see "your device is incompatible with this version"

How do I make it so that the older devices are able to download the older version?

Comment: Don't deactivate the old apk from Google App Store, or maybe I should say, move back the old apk to production

Comment: Yep, you can have multiple apk published for you app. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Should i Post it as Answer?

Comment: yes, moving the old one to production apparently doesnt remove the current one from production so both became active - awesome. Post this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to revert `minSdkVersion` value to 16 again.

Answer (score 0):

Below happens on minSdkVersion change

1. On apk upload, Google plays warns you on minSdkVersion telling how many users will be affected.
2. Existing users lower than minSdkVersion won't get update and cannot see app in PlayStore
3. Existing users lower than minSdkVersion, if they uninstall, cannot reinstall the application.

I suggest you use multiple apk option in PlayStore and continue to update your newer apk. Just keep the old one as it is.

Refer this : https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api